# hue error Could not connect to localhost:8003

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hue

We had installed cloudera CDH4.2 using tarball. But when try to launch hue in browser it gives error as Could not connect to localhost:8003.

Further in log file following error appears.

Failed to determine superuser of WebHdfs at http://'localhost':50070/webhdfs/v1/: 
Traceback (most recent call last):

Can somebody help me .

Regards,
Jayendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First error means that Beeswax could not start properly. The cause should show up in the logs.  The common solutions are sumed-up [here](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/hue-user/beeswax/hue-user/JBLcV4OqfH8/5jGYoim8T_cJ).

About WebHdfs, [this](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/Hue+Installation#HueInstallation-WebHDFSorHttpFSConfiguration) was probably not done completely.

Comment: WebHdfs is not listening on 'localhost'. After changing parameter it is working now.